# BeagleBoard not Responding - "smsc95xx 1-2.1:1.0: usb0: kevent 2 may have been dropped"

Tags: android, beagleboard

I am using Beagle Board XM OMAP3 with pre-build Android OS (ICS) running on it.

When I try running few executables, I get the following error and the board(through minicom) stops responding.

I don't face this problem when running some other executable.
Is my executables causing the board to stop responding?
Is it memory issue or something else?

This is the major error I noticed related to my issue:

> usb0: kevent 2 may have been dropped.
>
> kworker/0:1: page allocation failure. order:3, mode:0x20

This is the error I get :

```
Mem-info:
Normal per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:   90, btch:  15 usd:  78
active_anon:20255 inactive_anon:76 isolated_anon:0
active_file:6703 inactive_file:5133 isolated_file:0
unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
free:7369 slab_reclaimable:692 slab_unreclaimable:3824
mapped:11293 shmem:85 pagetables:609 bounce:0
Normal free:29476kB min:8192kB low:10240kB high:12288kB active_anon:81020kB 
inactive_anon:304kB active_file:26812kB inactive_file:20532kB unevio
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0
Normal: 3637*4kB 1164*8kB 351*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB    0*2048kB 
0*4096kB = 29476kB
11921 total pagecache pages
0 pages in swap cache
Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 0kB
65536 pages of RAM
8919 free pages
13506 reserved pages
4516 slab pages
55708 pages shared
0 pages swap cached
smsc95xx 1-2.1:1.0: usb0: kevent 2 may have been dropped
kworker/0:1: page allocation failure. order:3, mode:0x20


Backtrace: 
[<c004d65c>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x110) from [<c04bad00>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
r7:c06774d4 r6:c06774d4 r5:00000003 r4:00000020
[<c04bace8>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c00d504c>]                                      (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x524/0x5c4)
[<c00d4b28>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x0/0x5c4) from [<c00fb840>]     (__kmalloc_track_caller+0x318/0x634)
[<c00fb528>] (__kmalloc_track_caller+0x0/0x634) from [<c03ed95c>] (__alloc_skb+0x58/0xe8)
[<c03ed904>] (__alloc_skb+0x0/0xe8) from [<c02f3008>] (rx_submit+0x2c/0x1d4)
[<c02f2fdc>] (rx_submit+0x0/0x1d4) from [<c02f3ca0>] (usbnet_bh+0x17c/0x23c)
r9:00000000 r8:c06779b0 r7:00000005 r6:00000006 r5:00000004 r4:cf30f360
[<c02f3b24>] (usbnet_bh+0x0/0x23c) from [<c007acb4>] (tasklet_action+0x80/0xfc)
r7:c064238c r6:c068dd80 r5:c06779a0 r4:cf172000
[<c007ac34>] (tasklet_action+0x0/0xfc) from [<c007b494>] (__do_softirq+0xc8/0x1c8)
[<c007b3cc>] (__do_softirq+0x0/0x1c8) from [<c007b670>] (do_softirq+0x48/0x54)
[<c007b628>] (do_softirq+0x0/0x54) from [<c007b8d0>] (local_bh_enable+0x9c/0xc4)
r5:00000002 r4:c0675318
[<c007b834>] (local_bh_enable+0x0/0xc4) from [<c04000f0>]  (neigh_periodic_work+0x104/0x138)
r5:00000002 r4:c0675318
[<c03fffec>] (neigh_periodic_work+0x0/0x138) from [<c008ad84>]     (process_one_work+0x278/0x3f8)
[<c008ab0c>] (process_one_work+0x0/0x3f8) from [<c008cb94>] (worker_thread+0x218/0x410)
[<c008c97c>] (worker_thread+0x0/0x410) from [<c0090418>] (kthread+0x8c/0x94)
[<c009038c>] (kthread+0x0/0x94) from [<c0078750>] (do_exit+0x0/0x638)
r7:00000013 r6:c0078750 r5:c009038c r4:cf02fec0
```